# How to use variable name as table name in sql create statement

Tags: javascript, php, sql, mysqli, create-table

I need to create a new table in sql database based on input given by user.I want something like this

```
$query = "CREATE TABLE . $POST['name'] . (
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
);";
```

The user enters name in input text box and submits.Then the above query is called.Is it possible to create table dynamically with variable name.I am trying to do it in mysql. I am new to sql.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: use $_POST['name'] instead of $POST['name']

Comment: Do you get any errors? What have you tried? Also, you wouldn't use `$POST['']` you would need to do `$_POST['']`.

Comment: Yes I have changed it.. I am getting Error querying database when executing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could surround the variable with curly brackets, like this:

```
$query = "CREATE TABLE {$_POST['name']} (
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
)";
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question so that it could be useful for others...

Storing the POST variable previously in a local variable and giving the local variable in sql statment worked fine for me.

```
$table_name = $_POST['name'];

$query = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
)";
```

Comment: Care to explain why this fixed the issue?

Comment: May be the $_POST method cannot be used in sql query statements.   @Dale

Comment: As RoelVB suggested,the $POST can be used within braces '{' '}'

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "CREATE TABLE $_POST['name'] (
   PersonID int,
   LastName varchar(255),
   FirstName varchar(255),
   Address varchar(255),
   City varchar(255)
)";
```

your syntax is incorrect. that's all

Comment: But what i have tried is i stored the POST variable in a local variable and given it in sql statement.And now it works!!!